# Inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and application crashes

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) and launching the Demo sample, the app crashes:

```
Could not find method android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey, referenced from method android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.openPanel**

12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo/com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.DemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:29)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 11 more
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 24 more
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:133)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:249)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
12-11 15:52:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The third line of the error message says that in your XML file, the class `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is not found.

Have you well import `android.support.v7` library in your project?
Take a look here : https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: The first line of error messsage is : `Could not find method android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey` did you check if this method exists ?